# We/every one of us will earn 1 billion dollars - are they the same?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

Can "we" mean "every one of us"?

> "We will earn 1 billion dollars."

Can it mean "every one of us will earn 1 billion dollars?

Comment: “Everyone of us” is far from the first interpretation of *we* that your example sentence brings to mind.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't mean that.

You may want to say "Each of us will earn one billion dollars", or even better,

"We will earn one billion dollars each."

Putting "each" at the end emphasizes that the figure applies separately to every one of us.